The bode plot of proteus simulation and matlab transfer function is not same
I am trying to calculate bode plot of a circuit.
For proteus my frequency at -63dB is 18 kHz as sample the circuit connection and its bode plot is provided.


Using analytical approach I calculate the transfer function as

and its bode plot using matlab code is calculate using
R2=976;
R1=(998e3);
R3=22;
C=8200e-12;
num=([R2]);
den=([2*C*R3*R1+2*C*R3*R2 (R1+R2)]);
G=tf(num,den);
options = bodeoptions;
options.FreqUnits = 'Hz'; % or 'rad/second', 'rpm', etc.
figure(1)
bode(G,options);
grid on

The frequency for -63dB is 441 kHz.
Where am I making mistake please identify it?

Already the 1st line in your calculation is wrong. The first voltage divider is - of course - loaded by the succeeding sections.

Your are over complicating things by jumping into the math before simplifying things. For example consider what I have done below (shorted out the input signal): -

I've shorted it out because the circuit still has the same inherent RC time constant when the input is at 0 volts. From this, you can see that you can largely ignore R1A and R1B because they (together) are a thousand times the resistance of R2.
That leaves you with this: -

This means that the 8.2 nF capacitor is in parallel with 1020 Ω so, if you calculate RC on that basis you will arrive at around 19 kHz.
This is what an EE would do. What you did was attempt a mathematical route without simplifying the basic structure (never a good plan).

I solve the question using Nodal analysis and now my answer is correct.

Further these equations were solved by Matlab using minor-expansion
R3 = 22;
C = 8300e-12;
R2 = 976;
R1 = 998000;
syms s Vin
A = [-(1/R3), -C*s, (1/R3)+C*s;
    (1/R3) + (1/R2) + (1/R1), 0, -1/R3;
    0, (1/R3)+C*s, -C*s];
X = [-(1/R3), -C*s, 0;
    (1/R3) + (1/R2) + (1/R1), 0, Vin/R1;
    0, (1/R3)+C*s, 0];
%B = det(A);
B = det(A,'Algorithm','minor-expansion')
Y = det(X,'Algorithm','minor-expansion')
L = 47228722131631622161554866441955/2635146649435747461060372959951613029515264; %B[1]
M = 406459372473413/191817315328964165632; %B{2}
den = [L M];
N = 55187463665407821/145987464125023389879168401408000;%Y[1]
O = 302231454903657293676544/145987464125023389879168401408000; %Y[2]
num = [N O];
G = tf(num,den);
options = bodeoptions;
options.FreqUnits = 'Hz';
figure(1)
bode(G,options);
xlim([10 100000000])
grid on

Everyone thanks for the help

Simplify the problem by combining the obvious (the two 499k resistors). You can make a Thevenin equivalent as you tried to do, but not completely which left you with a mess.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Write your equation for the simplified version and graph. You'll get somewhere around 18 kHz at -63 dB. Be sure you convert the complex number in to magnitude (I'm not familiar with Matlab syntax, but I'm assuming that the bode option will give magnitude).
